# Is there a way to make Binding class throw back exceptions raised in bound objects?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, swallowed-exceptions

Consider the following class:

```
    public class Toto
    {
        string _Test = "try me!";

        public string Test
        {
            get { return _Test; }
            set { throw new Exception("This shouldn't be swallowed."); }
        }
    }
```

Right now, binding this object's Test property to a textbox and trying to type in a value will make the object throw an exception that will be swallowed by the Binding class.

The only way I've found to reach at the exception (other than within the property setter itself, of course) is by using the Binding's BindingComplete event.

Is there any way I can set up databinding so that it minds it's own business when it comes to exceptions it cannot possibly know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearantly Winform's databinding swallows exceptions and that's that. An horrible design, IMHO.